# Certain commands not working : make, wget - error message command not found

Tags: command-line, bash, execute-command

My system recently developed this error, certain commands are no longer working for example

`make -s` ,`wget`, `tar`

A brief description of the system I'm on `uname -a`

```
`Linux areahints-HP-15-Notebook-PC 4.15.0-46-lowlatency #49-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 6 10:23:17 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
```

I'm stuck and unsure as to how to proceed from this point on. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: What does `echo "$PATH"` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be due to the problem you have with the PATH. Easiest way to check it is by typing `echo $PATH` and post the output in here. If it's empty or incomplete then just type the following command in the terminal

`export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

This must solve most of the issue but if it doesn't try to reinstall `tar` , `make` and `wget`.